# How to resize webView according to screen and webpage resolution?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I loaded a webpage using `UIWebView`. But the problem is webPage loads carefully on safari. But in app `UIWebView` loads unscaled. I added constraints but it doesn't matter. You can see the screenshots by clicking the links below. How can I correct scales?

Note: I didn't disabled size classes.

[UIWebView](http://s1.postimg.org/jn8h34ja7/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_20_Aug_2015_14_49_12.png)

[Safari](http://s1.postimg.org/rep71onfj/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_20_Aug_2015_14_49_45.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Interface Builder` and check `Scales page to fit`

[image: Interface builder]